# Deploying reports with enabled Forms Based Authentication (FBA)

Tags: forms-authentication, reporting-services

Configuration:

- Sharepoint 2010
- Reporting Services Integrated Mode
- Claims Authentication with Windows Authentication (NTML) and Forms Based Authentication Enabled

I can deploy reports from Visual Studio with a FBA user but it doesn't work with a windows user (domain\user); both are site collection administrators.

Is it possible to deploy reports using a windows user when both Windows Authentication and FBA are enabled ? How ?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work with a windows user" what error does it actually show?  I ask this because I have a similar environment in SharePoint 2013 where I am repeatedly prompted for login credentials if I try to deploy using a Windows Auth account.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few situations where applications don't talk nicely to web apps with both authentication methods enabled, PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer being one of them - and I think Visual Studio being another.

You haven't stated if you're using 2008 (BIDS) or 2012 (SQL Server Data Tools)... I know a few bugs with SSRS in BIDS have been fixed in SSTD, so if you are able to try it out, you may find this particular issue has been fixed.

SQL Server Data Tools is available completely free: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh297027 - and is also a part of the SQL Server 2012 installation media.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still an issue on my SP2010 (June 2012 CU) / SSRS 2012 (SQL BI SP1) environment